# Apache redirect all non valid wildcard subdomains to root domain

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

Is it possible to redirect all 404 subdomain result to the root domain in apache2? Im using a wildcard subdomain entry in my DNS provider, and apache is set to fetch the site in the folder with the same name as the subdomain. But I would also like it to be able to redirect its self to the root domain if there is no folder.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Root domain
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
</VirtualHost>

# Wildcard subdomains
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/public
        # Redirect to root if `$0` folder doesn't exist
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is "%0"  valid syntax?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to a specific URL in www.example.com ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yeah %0 is valid inside `VirtualDocumentRoot`. And no just to the root would be great. For example, I might have a valid site `a.example.com`, but if someone goes to `b.example.com` I want them to be redirected to `example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite when the folder isn't there

```
# Redirect to root if `$0` folder doesn't exist
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond /var/www/%{SERVER_NAME}/public/ !-d
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I tried using DOCUMENT_ROOT, but didn't succeed

```
# RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-d
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! That works perfectly. I also had to enable the rewrite mod using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. So just in case anyone else has this issue, they know how to enable it. Thanks again!